# How can I refer to multiple turtles at once?

Tags: python

```
moon = trtl.Turtle()
earth = trtl.Turtle()
mars = trtl.Turtle()

turtles = [moon, earth, mars]

turtles[0].shape("circle")
```

I need a way to make the [] have all the turtles included.
I have tried [0,1,2] but it says it's a tuple.
The reason I'm not doing it separately is because I need to define a lot of other things about the turtles.

Comment: Is there a particular line that is erroring? Nothing in the code you've provided should be breaking. `turtles[0]` should properly reference `moon`.  Can you tease out what you mean by 'I have tried [0,1,2]` and where it is telling you 'it is a tuple'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be clear: the goal is to have some code run, `for` each `turtle` that is `in` the `turtles` list `:`? Does this remind you of any sort of code you have already seen? (Hint: try putting all the code in this comment together in order.) Also: please read [ask] and try to communicate clearly. The title here says "How can I define multiple turtles at once?" but the question is obviously not about *defining* the turtles because your code *already does that*.

Comment: One way you could do it is to define a turtle, set all of the properties, and use the `.clone()` method to make all of the other copies you want. https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.clone

Comment: @NathanielFord I assume that meant "I tried using `turtles[0, 1, 2].shape("circle")` and I got an error message that had the word `tuple` in it, which I don't remember, and don't see the value of reproducing or copying and pasting into the question".

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I wanted to define more than one turtle at a time, so I used a list. The problem I have come across is that I cannot seem to put more than one item in the list at a time. When I did this, 

turtles[0, 1, 2].shape("circle")

it gave an error saying it was a tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to address; first, the terminology you're using is not precise to what you're trying to ask. Secondly, you're indexing into an array in an inappropriate manner.

Terminology: when you 'define' a turtle, you are instantiating it. Like you do here:

```
trtl.Turtle()
```

The `moon =` you place in front assigns the return value of the Turtle instantiation to a name. Similarly, when you create your list, you're assigning elements to that list:

```
turtles = [moon, earth, mars]
```

Note that the 'list' here is `turtles` and it does have three items in it. (Thus, claiming the list cannot have more than one item is inaccurate.) What you were really trying to say was 'you can't refer to more than one item in the list at a time'.

Then you want to index into the list, and in your case you're trying to run a function on each turtle in that list. But the way you're doing that is by passing a tuple into the list indexing. This doesn't work. From the REPL:

```
>>> ls = [1,2,3]
>>> len(ls)
3
>>> ls[0,1,2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Effectively, `ls[0,1,2]` is taking the list built (`[1,2,3]`) and asking for items from it with a tuple, the `0,1,2` part, which is an invalid way to reference a point in the list. (Note, the `len(ls)` shows us the list has three items in it, so we know we constructed the list correctly.) The `0,1,2` here is a tuple because Python considers values delimited by commas as tuples in most cases, and so the error message is telling you what you need to know: you passed in a tuple and it expected either an integer or a slice. What you're really trying to do is run a function on each element of the list, which means you need to *iterate over the list*.

As Karl pointed out, this requires the use of some variation of a loop, such as a `for` loop. Note that you can index into one element just fine, such as when you did `turtles[0].circle()`. You just need to change the `0` part of that statement in a loop.

Remember, to ask the question properly, you should ensure that you're including the actual code you're running, with the actual result. That will yield better and quicker results in the future.